# Unity - Setting Skybox from script makes strange color

Tags: c#, colors, skybox

I downloaded some skyboxes from the Unity Store to make a night scene.

By setting a night skybox, it makes it all dark and this worked great; nothing can be seen without a light source!

But I made a really simple script to just change the default skybox to the night one, which accomplishes this, but you can still see everything in a grayish color.

## Code

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SceneEditor : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material skybox;

    void Start () {

        RenderSettings.skybox = skybox;
        RenderSettings.ambientSkyColor = skybox.color;
    }
}
```

## Screen Shot

[image: night sky]

Comment: So the problem is when you set programatically the night skybox you downloaded, it is not as dark as if you set that skybox as default in the editor? Or even if you set it manually in the editor it doesnt work neither?

Comment: When I set it in the editor it works great. It doesn't work when scripted